# Why are exchange rates fixed for prolonged periods of time?

Tags: foreign-exchange, eur-euro

Sometimes I see the following pattern when observing the history of an exchange rate:

[image]

That is for several days the exchange rate becomes constant. What causes this?

My best guess is that some powerful entity, such as a central bank or a major investment fund willfully maintains a certain level by automated trading.

Comment: Just glancing at some graphs, all the ones I see occur on weekends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FX markets trade [24 hours a day during the week, but not at weekends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_market). Perhaps there's a small amount of after-hours or off-market activity, but broadly there wouldn't be much activity between 2200UTC on Friday (21st Nov on your plot) and 2200UTC on Sunday (23rd Nov on your plot).